# Plotting a text file by using gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a text file called data.txt and it looks like this:

```
0 0.0025 sec    
1 0.254 sec     
2 0.5654 sec
```

I want to plot it by using gnuplot. When I enter gnuplot my command line look like this;

```
gnuplot >
```

What do I have to do now to plot my text file and view it?

Comment: Have you considered reading the gnuplot documentation? http://www.gnuplot.info/documentation.html

Comment: this has absolutely nothing to do with python just so you know

Comment: This is probably the most basic question there could be about gnuplot and although I hate saying it, probably falls into RTFM territory.  This question should probably be closed for that reason.  Google "gnuplot tutorial" to get started.  I also recommend "Gnuplot In Action".  The documentation itself may not be helpful, as it is more of a reference, once you know what you are doing.  Feel free to ask about anything you may not understand after starting with a basic tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the bare minimum required to plot that data is to have a program file that looks like this:

```
set title "SAMPLE"
set terminal canvas
plot [-19:19] 'data.dat'
```

Setting the `terminal` to `canvas` means it will output an `html canvas`, if you want any different output you need to look into the documentation

then in the terminal you can type:

```
gnuplot < PROGRAM_FILE > OUTPUT.html
```

That should get you started, but you really should look into the documentation if you want to do anything more.